# Rails form_for wrong controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, railstutorial.org

Right out of the Rails Tutorial. I can't get the sign in form to call the create method. Debug shows it only calls the new action. I had no issues setting up the users which also has a database so the following was utilized:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
```

In this case, with no model, I'm doing as the tutorial suggests:

```
<%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>
```

A quick glance at rake routes shows the route is valid:

```
Prefix Verb      URI Pattern                 Controller#Action                                                                                                                                                                                   
   root GET      /                           site_pages#root                                                                                                                                                                                     
  about GET      /about(.:format)            site_pages#about                                                                                                                                                                                    
 signup GET      /signup(.:format)           users#new                                                                                                                                                                                           
signout DELETE   /signout(.:format)          sessions#destroy                                                                                                                                                                                    
 signin GET      /signin(.:format)           sessions#new                                                                                                                                                                                        
  users POST     /users(.:format)            users#create                                                                                                                                                                                        
new_user GET     /users/new(.:format)        users#new                                                                                                                                                                                           
user GET         /users/:id(.:format)        users#show                                                                                                                                                                                          
        DELETE   /users/:id(.:format)        users#destroy                                                                                                                                                                                       
sessions POST    /sessions(.:format)         sessions#create                                                                                                                                                                                     
new_session GET  /sessions/new(.:format)     sessions#new                                                                                                                                                                                        
session DELETE   /sessions/:id(.:format)     sessions#destroy
```

Not sure what I'm missing. Been messing with it for over an hour. Tried changing to form_tag and it's still reacting in the same way. I've edited the routes and the form in multiple ways to trigger the correct functioning with no luck.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Controller added:

```
def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        #SIGN IN AND REDIRECT
    else
        flash.now[:danger] = "Invalid Submission. Please Try Again."
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Comment: Consider it a Rails unsolved mystery. 

I changed:
<%= f.submit "Log In", class: "btn btn-primary btn-width-30" %>

to:
<%= f.submit %>

And it worked. I then changed it back and it still worked. I have no idea.

Comment: You can always post explicitly method: :post to your `form_for` to not invoke get method: `form_for(:session, url: sessions_path, method: :post)`

Comment: Why not use Devise gem?

Comment: Getting there soon Michael.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
      <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %> 

            <%= render 'layouts/flash' %> 

            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.text_field :email %>

            <%= f.label :password %>
            <%= f.password_field :password %>

            <%= f.submit "Log In", class: "btn btn-primary btn-width-30" %>

       <% end %>
</div>
```